# Azure Pipelines YAML SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 120

Tags: sql, azure, yaml, pipeline, dacpac

Running an Azure pipeline passing back an output value from Bicep to the Yaml. That value is the connection string used in the task to deploy a `.dacpac`. I am receiving the following message. The index position is pointing to the end of the connection string at the semi colon.

`##[error]Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 120.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-`

Tried several different combinations of values to see if some characters in the password needed to be escaped or if I misspelled the database name or user id. I followed the documentation for the specific task on how to format the connection string. I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong here.

The pipeline yaml step.

```
 - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
   displayName: Update database
   inputs:
     azureSubscription: ***
     authenticationType: connectionString
     connectionString: $(outputs.sqlDefaultConnectionString.value)
     dacpacFile: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.Build.dacpac
```

The output string from Bicep.
`'Server=${sqlServer.name}${environment().suffixes.sqlServerHostname};Database=db${appName};User ID=${administratorLogin};Password=${administratorLoginPassword};'`

The value in the pipeline omitting the actual credentials:
`Server=***.database.windows.net;Database=***;User ID=***;Password=***;`

Following Microsoft document it states:

```
ConnectionString - Connection String
string. Required when AuthenticationType = connectionString.

Specifies the Azure SQL Server connection string, like Server=testServer.database.windows.net;Database=testdb;User ID=AccountPlaceholder;Password=$(securePassword);.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment-v1?view=azure-pipelines

**Edit 2022-11-18:**
Changing the authentication type to server and required arguments to the following is a workaround and did succesfully complete the task.

```
    - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
      displayName: Update database
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ***
        authenticationType: server
        serverName: $(outputs.sqlServerName.value)
        databaseName: $(outputs.sqlDatabaseName.value)
        sqlUsername: ***
        sqlPassword: $(administratorLoginPassword)
        dacpacFile: '**/*.dacpac'
```